# Gnosis.js will not perform createEvent request when initialized using Metamask's web3

Tags: web3js, metamask

I'm trying to create an event on the Morden testnet via the gnosis api but `gnosis.createEvent` will not make the necessary request.

I am able to load metamask's web3 into the config object I use to initialize the gnosis config.

```
config.web3 = customWeb3
```

I see that `config.account` is set to my correct metamask wallet address and I'm able to call `getEvents` and `updateEventDescriptions` successfully.

However, when I call `getEvent(description, config.account, config)`, no request is made.

When I do not set  metamask's web3 in the config

```
config.web3 = customWeb3
```

I can make the request, but receive an 'Invalid Signature' error from the api endpoint. I presume this is because in this case the default `config.account` loaded by gnosis does not belong to me.

I see that metamask's web3 version is 17.0 and the web3 provided without explicitly setting

```
config.web3 = customWeb3
```

is  15.3.

Why no request when I explicitly set `config.web3` as above?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I had a malformed event description that did not contain a valid `feeToken` value.